# foreach random no match

Tags: foreach, csh

This is for code:

```
set source_failed = `cat mine.log`

set dest_failed = `cat their.log`

foreach t ($source_failed)
  set isdiff = 0
  set sflag = 0
  foreach t2 ($dest_failed)
    if ($t2 == $t) then
      set sflag = 1
      break
    endif
  end
  ...
end
```

Problem is that the inner foreach loop runs okay for first few 10 iterations. After that iteration, suddenly I got

```
foreach: no match
```

Moreover, I am iterating over the array of strings, not files. What is the reason behind this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is (probably) that `mine.log` and/or `their.log` contain special globbing characters, such as `*` or `?`. The shell will try to expand this to a file. There are no matches for this accidental pattern, and hence the error "no match".

The easiest way to prevent this behaviour is to add `set noglob` to the top. From `tcsh(1)`:

```
    noglob  If set, Filename substitution and Directory stack  substitution
           (q.v.)  are  inhibited.   This  is most useful in shell scripts
           which do not deal with filenames, or after a list of  filenames
           has been obtained and further expansions are not desirable.
```

You can re-enable this behaviour by using `set glob`.

Alternativly, you can use `:q`. From `tcsh(1)`:

```
Unless  enclosed in `"' or given the `:q' modifier the results of variable
substitution may eventually be command and  filename  substituted.

[..]

When the `:q' modifier is applied to a substitution the variable will expand
to multiple words with  each  word  sepa rated  by  a blank and quoted to
prevent later command or filename sub stitution.
```

But you need to be very careful about quoting when you use the variable. In the below example, the `echo` command will fail if you don't add quotes (`set noglob is much easier`):

```
set source_failed = `cat source`

foreach t ($source_failed:q)
    echo "$t"
end
```